# MongoDB on Google Cloud Launcher connect to Flask Application

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine, google-cloud-launcher

I just found out about google cloud launcher has MongoDB, so we decided to use Cloud launcher instead of mlab, seems little different to how mlab works

How do I connect google cloud launcher MongoDB to Flask Application?